# List of globally available shortcuts on a Windows system including 3rd party

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to get a list of globally available shortcuts on a Windows system, including 3rd party software?

Random examples:

- WndHop - <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move a window between monitors
- Dexpot - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to open task switcher
- Launchy - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

My goal is to track down shortcut conflicts. Most of the above software can be customised to change the shortcuts aside from WndHop, the later which is not working for me, probably due to a conflict. Currently winkey+enter toggles a windows normal size and maximised, I'm not sure what introduced this shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean "currently registered global shortcuts"?

Comment: My bad, can someone with permission move this please to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that it would be possible to find all 3rd party short cuts. If an application has created a global keyboard hook to listen for a certain keyboard event there's no way that Windows can tell which keys will make it do various things.

Answer (score 1):

Gathering a universal Shortcut list seems like rather a long winded way to achieve the result you want.

Instead I would suggest a process of elimination.

Start to eliminate apps running on your machine one by one by killing them off using either Task Manager or Process Explorer.

After killing off each of your programs, attempt the key combo in question again and if the action still occurs, then you have not yet found the program in question.

Eventually the effect in question will cease, and you'll know that the last app you killed off was causing this behaviour.

Comment: Of course the process of elimination approach is the way to go to find my conflict. This is a regular issue for me, of which this is a particular example. I guess there is no way of telling what shortcuts have been introduced by other software since they are not registered anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Windows PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) which has a very useful Shortcut guide that shows the available shortcuts for the current state of the desktop.
2. The activation shortcut is customizable and the default is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
   (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> is easier to remember).
3. A pop-up overlay shows the available shortcuts.